# Calculus finding critical points

Tags: calculus

Find the Critical Points for this equation:

$$x e^x = 0$$

I know its going to be either 0 or 1 but how do I get there? Thanks

Comment: Functions or functionals have critical points.  I've never heard anyone refer to a critical point of an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *equation*

$xe^x = 0 \tag{1}$

has exactly one solution, $x = 0$, since $e^x \ne 0$ for all $x$.  If one defines a *critical point* in the usual sense to be a point where the derivative of a function is zero, then one needs to consider a function for sense to be made; in this case I suppose we should set

$y(x) = xe^x; \tag{2}$

then

$y'(x) = e^x + xe^x \tag{3}$

and if we want $x$ such that $y'(x) = 0$, we must have

$e^x + xe^x = 0, \tag{4}$

implying

$x  = -1. \tag{5}$

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: HEy Robert, Thanks a lot for your help. My first question in itself was after finding the derivative for an equation and setting it equal to 0. So i already did that work. In that case, the critical point is 0 right? I think what you did was went on to take the second derivative, which is very much appreciated haha. Just wanted to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: @ user108114:  glad to help out.  Yeah, if $y'(x) = xe^x$ then the critical point is $x = 0$.  Note from what I wrote the second derivative is positive at $x = 0$, so $0$ is a local minimum for $y(x)$.  And thanks for the "acceptance"! ;-)!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative: $e^x+x*e^x=0$ Factor out the e-power to get your critical value(s)